# Prevent user to go to login page after successful login in django

Tags: django, redux, django-authentication, django-login

I am using Django-redux for authentication purpose. My question is how can I prevent to go to registration page or login page if the user is authenticated.

settings.py

```
REGISTRATION_OPEN = True 
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True 
REGISTRATION_FORM = 'signin.forms.MyRegForm'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/signin/user_sign/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from signin import views

app_name = 'signin'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user_sign/', views.user_sign, name='user_sign'),
]
```

views.py

```
def user_sign(request):
    print('user_sign')
    obj = UserSelection.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if obj.user_type == 'candidate':
        return redirect('candidate:cand_dash')

    else:
        return redirect('employer:employer_dash')
```

Answer (score 0):

In login or registration views, just check that the user is authenticated or not

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # Do something for authenticated users.
    ...
else:
    # Do something for anonymous users.
    ...
```

Comment: I am not using django default authentication, in this case I am using django-registration-redux.